# 60 minutes to shut down sql server service?

Tags: sql-server

We recently merged with a new company and they have a server that has 265 DBs on it (6.6tb of mdfs). Shortly after we merged the other DBA said it takes 60 minutes to shut down the services which I thought was incredibly high. Last night they stopped and started the services and sure enough it took 60 minutes. I looked at the log this morning and found the following error messages in the sql log file while it was in the process of trying to stop the service.

I know SQL takes a longer time to start back up if you have a lot of VLFs, but it only took 1 minute from the time it started up until the Recovery Complete message appeared in the log. Any idea if 60 mins is normal? Or if not, what can I do to investigate speeding this up. Thanks!

```
 Error: 17142, Severity: 14, State: 0.
 SQL Server service has been paused. No new connections will be allowed. To resume the     
 service, use SQL Computer Manager or the Services application in Control Panel.

 Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 13.
 Login failed for user ''. Reason: SQL Server service is paused. 
 No new connections can be accepted at this time. [CLIENT: xx.xxx.xx.xx]
```

Comment: What are the specs on the server and SQL version?

Comment: A bit more info I just received, he pauses the service first (which is why I see those errors). Is there a benefit to that? I have always just stopped the services directly.

Comment: @JohnM Its a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4650 0 @ 2.70GHz with 1tb of memory. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3412.0 (X64) 
 Mar  2 2014 01:25:09 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
Let me know if there is anything else specifically you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, and it has 32 cores.

Comment: I don't think pausing before a shutdown is really necessary, do you know what portion of that 60 minutes is allocated to the pausing versus the actual shutdown?

Comment: @JohnM Not that I know... is there a way to tell in the SQL Logs or a way to tell next time we do this shut down to determine how long it is in pause vs actual shutdown?

Comment: Here is a dump of a pause then shutdown I just performed http://pastebin.com/n5YbWaDf via the SQL Server logs - the start the shutdown is easy to differentiate from the pause.

Comment: @JohnM Thanks. So if I'm reading that correctly, the actual Stop does not start until "SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required." comes across in the log? If so,then 99% of that time it was spent in pause. I will ask him why he does pause first and if we can just do stop immediately next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't take 60 minutes to shutdown the server. As you mentioned, the DBA is performing a pause before shutting down - this is probably the major contributor to the slow shutdown.

Unless he's planning to resume the database, there isn't normally reason to pause. Removing this step from the procedure should cut down a significant portion of the 60 minutes.

Here is an [example of a log](http://pastebin.com/n5YbWaDf) that shows a pause followed by a shutdown.

The pause begins at:

```
SQL Server IS NOT allowing NEW connections because the Service Control Manager
requested a pause. TO resume the service<c/> USE SQL Computer Manager OR the Services
application IN Control Panel.
```

And the shutdown sequence begins with:

```
SQL Server IS terminating IN response TO a 'stop' request FROM Service Control
Manager. This IS an informational message ONLY. No USER action IS required.
```

Check with the DBA first though, to make sure there isn't a specialized case that necessitates the pause.

Comment: I would imagine when you `Stop` a service which is `Pause`d, it has to `Continue` it before it can further `Stop` it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to how much time it will take to ***stop*** a sql server instance will depend on :

- how many user connections are currently connected to sql server ? SQL server has to *disable* all the logins except sysadmins. SO this could take some time depending on how many connections are active when you send a "shutdown" signal to sql server instance.
- SQL Server has to perform an [internal CHECKPOINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189573.aspx) on each ONLINE databases. Note that OFFLINE databases are not counted in this process.
- SQL server will [wait for all activity (e.g. all tsql queries, stored procedures, transactions, etc) to finish.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189095(v=sql.90).aspx)

[Pausing a SQL Server is different](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175957(v=sql.105).aspx) as

> When you pause an instance of Microsoft SQL Server, users that are connected to the server can finish tasks, but new connections are not allowed. For example, **you can pause an instance of SQL Server for a few minutes and send a shutdown message to connected users before shutting it down.** You can also resume a SQL Server service.

So to answer your question,

> 60 minutes to shut down sql server service?

Ideally, it should not take 60 mins , but again it depends on what you are doing. If you are pausing and then stopping sql server then it probably might.

If your entire goal is to stop sql server, then I would suggest you to (in maintenance window) :

- Shutdown your web application. This will kill most of the connections to sql server.
- Then shutdown sql server using :

  - Stop sql server using Services console .
  - Shutting down your sql server using configuration manager.
  - running SHUTDOWN command in SSMS (do not use SHUTDOWN with NOWAIT !)